# How do check if another application window is open on my machine (i.e., iterate through all open windows)?

Tags: c#, windows, loops

I have an app that writes a series of text files to a folder on the user's machine.  It then prompts them if they would like to open the folder to view all the files.  I use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() to do this and it works well.  However, if there is already a window with that folder open, I would just like to reuse that window instead of opening another one.  Helps keep things tidy.

Any ideas?

**Update**: I tried this:

```
        if (MessageBox.Show("Compiled!  Open folder?", "Compile Done", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo("explorer", Path);
            Info.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process.Start(Info);
        }
```

But it still opens a new window.  I also tried setting UseShellExecute to true and I get the same result of a new window opening up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tried this on Windows XP:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Dev");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Dev");
```

And it opened my C:\Dev folder. I then focused elsewhere. After 10 seconds, the C:\Dev window flashed and was highlighted again. So what are you doing different where it *isn't* working?

(Trying to find out if there's an open window displaying a particular folder is fraught and error prone. I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Hey, this worked!  I guess windows automatically associates raw folder paths with Explorer and this somehow just happens to allow it work how I want.  I guess explicitly calling explorer.exe and passing the folder path as a parameter forces a new Explorer instance every time.  Thanks, mate!

Comment: Also, even if I have other Explorer windows open to different folders, this code reuses only the folder that points to the path I am trying to open.  Other windows remain unaffected.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [`ShellExecute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to open the folder then Explorer will do the work for you and re-use an open Explorer window if one exists.

The .net way to call `ShellExecute()` is to set the [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) property of the `ProcessStartInfo` object that is passed to `Process.Start()`.

---

**Update**

Having now posted your code I can see the problem.  You should ask the system to open the folder rather than trying to start a new explorer.exe process, as so:

```
ProcessStartInfo Info = new ProcessStartInfo(Path);
Process.Start(Info);
```

Comment: The Process class uses ShellExecuteEx() by default.

Comment: @hans thanks. Can't imagine why it doesn't behave as expected for OP.

Comment: I put the code I tried in my original post.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, you say that windows will just reuse an existing Explorer window.  Not just any Explorer window, right?  If I have other Explorer windows open, I don't want them to be used.  I only want the Explorer window that's currently open to the folder I am trying to open to be reused.

Comment: Disregard.  The other answerer here provided the solution that works as I need.  I don't understand exactly how it works, but I stated my theory in his answer.  Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin My answer is fine too. The key is that you were previously opening explorer.exe when in fact the correct thing to do is to open the folder.

Comment: You are correct, and I apologize for overlooking that.  The other solution prevented the middle-man use of a ProcessStartInfo object.  I wish I could mark both as the answer, but the other solution is more streamlined as it does the bare minimum of what I am trying to accomplish.  I did upvote your answer, though.

Comment: @oscilating no worries it's easy to overlook such things. That's why stack overflow exists.