# Wait for application window to open then do something

Tags: c#

I am very new to C# but I am fast learning. I have seen various answers to this but I'm not sure they suite, or maybe I'm just not getting them.

I have a business requirement to write a c# app that sites in the system tray and runs when a certain action has been performed in Internet Explorer. This action (for now) is the opening of the about internet explorer window. I need the app to constantly monitor to see if this window is open and then run some code, an example would be close the about window and display a message box.

I have managed to get the system tray part working, how would i go about monitoring that the window exists?

EDIT
To answer some of the questions in the comments:
At work we use a booking system that only runs in IE, we are looking for a way to automate a section of our manual process, to do this we are thinking that we can have the following process:
go to booking, click help > about, system tray app closes the window and runs some code to update the database. that's pretty much it.

I have had a look at some of the following:
[How to check if window is opned and close it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240709/how-to-check-if-window-is-opned-and-close-it)
[c#: How do check if another application window is open on my machine (i.e., iterate through all open windows)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883294/c-how-do-check-if-another-application-window-is-open-on-my-machine-i-e-iter)

I think i understand that I have to look through the running processes and check there relevant programs properties to see if it has the correct window name? Im sure i can get that to work (eventually) however it was the waiting for that window to open part that i am stuck with, does C# have a waitfor or do i have to write a function to constantly check that window is open?

**EDIT**

I have accepted @Adrian's answer as it looks like it will do want i wanted; however after reading all the comments I went to my manager and we discussed this. We will now go down the route of having the user enter the booking number into the C# App its self via a text box in the right click menu. Thanks all.

Comment: And why should your app have permission to mess with the windows opened by *another* application?

Comment: What have you tried? What's wrong with the answers you've seen? What are the answers you've seen? Why don't they work for you?

Comment: That is... *absolutely* the strangest behavior I have ever heard of for an application. If you want to automate a task, just give the user a button to click. Don't tie it to a critical system function. What happens when IT needs to see what version of IE that is running on a machine? They go to Help -> About, and all of a sudden, stuff starts getting booked automatically. Whoops!!

Comment: I absolutely agree @Cody Gray; however this is exactly what was done before me and management want to keep the same process, regardless of how inefficient it is..

Comment: Well then...how did they do it?

Comment: I am not privy to that, the code has since been "lost", else i would have modified that code..

Comment: Wouldn't a bookmark to a web app/page be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the FindWindowEx API call

See here for example code:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/findwindowex.html

Then SendMessage to close the window.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html

But you will be limited to what events you can capture/use from other applications...for security reasons. Unless the app specifically allows such interactions.

Comment: In addition to the problems you hinted at towards the bottom of your answer, a solution involving the `FindWindowEx` function will *also* be one that involves constant polling...not a very good solution if you care about speed or reliability. Or preventing heavy performance degradation.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use AutoIt. It is a freeware desktop automation tool that also offers a .NET class library for integration.
With this, you can check and wait until a certain window is opened fairly easy.

You can download this tool from here:
https://www.autoitscript.com